# React.js and .net core Network error: Failed to fetch

Tags: reactjs, .net-core

Each time I do a yarn start, the application usually displays the error in the browser console:

```
"Network error: Failed to fetch"
```

I have tried a lot of suggestions online but none worked for me. Here is the errors I am getting from browser navigator[image: Error from browser console]

Any ideas how to fix this will be appreciated.

Comment: Provide more details about your back-end

Comment: Where is the backend hosted? is it in the same domain:port ? Is the service urls accessible via browser url or using postman or any other rest client?

Comment: My backend is .net core c#, hosted on the same VM.  The server side runs on localhost 5000 while the front end runs on localhost 3000.  Yes it is accessible via browser url.